# Got -1 from HttpURLConnection getResponseCode()

Tags: java

In my code I use

```
mHttpConnRespCode = mConnection.getResponseCode();
```

to get http response code, where mConnection is HttpURLConnection type.

Sometimes I got -1 as response code. Under what circumstances, mConnection.getResponseCode() returns -1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get -1 when there is no Status Code available. For example, this will happen in following scenarios,

1. Response is not received yet.
2. Response is not valid HTTP response.